# I am trying to replace a text for example

Tags: vim, awk, sed, grep

Example:

```
"word" -nothing
```

To

```
word" - nothing
```

in gvim.

I tried

```
:%s/^.*\"/
```

But what I get is:  -nothing

Well I am new to scripting so I would like to  know if it can be done in any other way like using gvim or awk or sed.

Comment: Instead of `%s/^.*\"/` try `%s/\v(")(.*)/\2/g`. To read about how capturing groups work in Vim do `:help pattern-atoms` or `:help \1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vim... Check for `\(`word + quote + space + hyphen`\)` as first reference, followed directly by another `\(`word`\)` as second reference... replace by first reference + space + second reference...  Make sure the find/replace can happen multiple times on a line with `g` suffix.

```
:%s/\(\w" -\)\(\w\)/\1 \2/g
```

Note that I left out the leading quote... I suppose it is possible you might have spaces in the quoted text - and I think this form might be better for you. Now in sed, that is the really cool thing about the relationship between *nix tools - they all use similar (or the same) regular expressions pattern language.  So, the same exact pattern as above can be done in sed (using `:` as delimiter for clarity).

```
sed 's:\(\w" -\)\(\w\):\1 \2:g'
```

Awk doesn't do back references; so, not to say it can't be done, but it is not so convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{sub(/^"/,"");sub(/-/,"- ")} 1'   Input_file
```

***Solution 2nd***: With `sed`.

```
sed 's/^"//;s/-/- /'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to replace first `"` in each line with empty string. So in `sed` it is just:

```
sed 's/"//'
```

Without `g` flag it will replace only first occurrence in each line.

**EDIT:**

The same way it will work in Vim (unless you have `'gdefault'` option set), so in Vim you can:

```
:%s/"//
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you also tagged `grep`: GNU grep has the `-P` switch for PCRE (Perl compatible reg ex) which has `\K`: *Keep the stuff left of the \K, don't include it in $&*, so:

```
$ echo \"word\" | grep -oP "\"\Kword\""
word"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

:%s/\"(.*)\"/\1\"/gc